# Bootstrap Toogle fail after ajax request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap-toggle

I am using Ajax and Bootstrap toogle and try when I click on a row into my index.php to load option.php using Ajax. First time, Bootstrap toogle seem to running and switching perfect but when I click another row, I am not able to switch. 
Here is my index.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Table</div>
        <div style="height:280px;" class="card-body">
            <div class="overflow">
                <table id="tablaPisos" class="table" data-click-to-select="true" data-single-select="true"
                    data-toggle="tablaPisos">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="1">Col1</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Col2</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Col3</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Col4</th>
                            <th colspan="2">Col5</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="1">1</td>
                        <td colspan="2">1</td>
                        <td colspan="2">1</td>
                        <td colspan="2">1</td>
                        <td colspan="2">1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="1">2</td>
                        <td colspan="2">2</td>
                        <td colspan="2">2</td>
                        <td colspan="2">2</td>
                        <td colspan="2">2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="1">3</td>
                        <td colspan="2">3</td>
                        <td colspan="2">3</td>
                        <td colspan="2">3</td>
                        <td colspan="2">3</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).on('click', '#tablaPisos tr', function(event){
            var value="1212";
            var video="Yes";
            $.ajax({
                   type: 'GET',
                    url: 'option.php',
                           data: {name: value, generado: video},
                            success: function(data) {
                                //$("#imageContainer").append(data);
                                $("#imageContainer").html(data);


                            }, error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                    alert(xhr.status);
                                    alert(thrownError);
                                }

                        });
        });
    </script>

<div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Image</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                     <div id ="imageContainer" class="overflow">

                    </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I use Get form on Ajax, it load the option.php:

```
    <?php
    echo"It works";
?>

<head>
    <link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    ul{list-style:none}

    </style>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sortable1").sortable({
        stop: function (event, ui) {
        },
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var counter = 1;
            $('input[name="checkImg"]').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('posicion', counter);

            });
        }
        }).disableSelection();
        });

</script>

<ul class="justify-content-center col-11 connectedSortable" id="sortable1">
<div style="border:solid border-width: 1px;">
        <li name="list" class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="checkbox" id="input1" name="checkImg" data-height="10" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini"

            data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" >
             Image </li>


    </div>
    <div style="border:solid border-width: 1px;">
        <li name="list" class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="checkbox" id="input2" name="checkImg" data-height="10" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="mini"

            data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" >
             Image 2 </li>


    </div>

</ul>
```

Images:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help will be welcome, thanks.

Comment: First of all, there seems to be a typo `$(this).attr('posicion', counter);`. Second, I think the way you're a including the BootstrapToggle library may be the problem: a html document shouldn't have more than one `head` tag.

Comment: `$(this).attr('posicion', counter)`, is for another thing. Do you think that affects? If I include the BootstrapToggle inside index.php, option.php doesnt recognize this library. @KevinPastor

Comment: One thing you could try is including the script at the end of your options `body`. The other option would be to look at the docs to see if BootstrapToggle has an initialization function to look the DOM for new elements.

Comment: May I include after all body in script.php or index.php?

Comment: In an ideal world, you should be loading content separatly from scripts. jQuery lets you do this using `$.getScript`

Comment: So I need to add `$.getScript` to the end of script.php only?

Comment: In your index script, you first have to get the option DOM content, and after you've added it to the DOM (at the end of the `success` callback), you should call `$.getScript`.

Comment: I try adding: 
`          
   `success: function(data) {
                                //$("#imageContainer").append(data);
                                $("#imageContainer").html(data);
                                $.getScript("https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js");`

But still not working. Did I get script well? @KevinPastor

Comment: Any idea? @KevinPastor

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm out of idea...